# preventing two identical files from being uploaded React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to prevent duplicate files from being added to the state?

```
export const Files = React.memo(() => {
  const [uploadFiles, setFiles] = React.useState([]);

  const handleFile = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files;
    setFiles(uploadFiles.concat([...file]));
  };

  console.log(uploadFiles);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" multiple onChange={handleFile} />
      {uploadFiles && uploadFiles?.map((f) => <div>{f.name}</div>)}
    </div>
  );
});
```

as a result, I can output 2 identical files. But I need only 1
can be like that before adding to compare file names and remove them from the mass state?

Comment: What have you tried so far?